# Как правильно совместить настройки iredmail и nginx?

Tags: nginx, email

Нужно получить работоспособный веб (сделал) и почтовый сервер (работает, кроме веб-интерфейса)
На чистую ubuntu поставил iredmail, создал служебный адрес, после чего перенес конфигурацию существовавшего веб-сервера (nginx, php, mysql) - настроил и она работает, но не получается совместить настройки iredmail для nginx c существующей конфигурацией веб-сервера.

iredmail поставил /opt/www/iredadmin и /opt/www/roundcubemail
Нужно сделать их доступными domain.ru/iredadmin и domain.ru/roundcube но у меня это  получается.

В nginx.conf - общие настройки и включающие
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels= keys_zone=wholepage:50m;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  192.168.1.6 domain.ru www.domain.ru;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
#   rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 81920; #Fix for largest URI
    etag on;    
    expires 3d;
    if ($host ~ !^(domain.ru|www.domain.ru)$) {
            rewrite ^ http://www.domain.ru$request_uri? permanent;  
}

location /static {
    root /data;
    expires max;
}   


       location / {
            root   /var/www/domain;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;

    location ~* ^/roundcube {
#        auth_basic "Admin Login";
#        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pass/roundcube_pass;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        }
        # deny running scripts inside writable directories
        location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
                return 403;
                error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            root  /var/www/domain;
#       if_modified_since off;
#       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;  
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass_header Last-Modified;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Если строка fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket; в
    location ~* ^/roundcube закомментирована, то index.php загружается, как бинарный файл, если раскомментирована, то в логе ошибка 
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script  has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream
Хотя в security.limit_extensions прописаны нужные расширения.

Как правильно настроить?

Comment: [это читали](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23393266/4827341)?

Comment: Прочитал, выполнил по списку, в результате domain.ru/roundcube file not found.   В логе *43490 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: .... , server: .... , req
uest: "GET /roundcube/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket:", host: "domain.ru"